# What's the correct datetime format for this string date generated by python?

Tags: python, django

I have this date example **'2022-08-30T11:53:52.204219'** stored in database, when I get it from database it's type is string so I wanted to convert it to a date type by using this python code

```
datetime.strptime('2022-08-30T11:53:52.204219', "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

I also tried this one

```
datetime.strptime('2022-08-30T11:53:52.204219', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

But I always get this error response **'time data '2022-08-30T11:53:52.204219' does not match format "%Y-%m-%d'T'%H:%M:%S.%f'**
I need help to convert this string date to an actual date

Comment: Use `datetime.strptime('2022-08-30T11:53:52.204219', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")` Remove the `'T'` and only add `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime('2022-08-30T11:53:52.204219', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

Result:

```
2022-08-30 11:53:52.204219
```